# shell script make symbolic link(specific string pattern change)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In Test Dir

```
Test (Dir)
  -> 20171101 (Dir)
  -> 20171102 (Dir)
        -> images (Dir)
        -> test.apple.1.txt
  -> 20171103 (Dir)
        -> images (Dir)
        -> test.apple.2.txt
```

I want to make symbolic link below :

```
Test2 (Test's symbolic link)
  -> 20171101 (Dir)
  -> 20171102 (Dir)
        -> images (Dir)
        -> test.banana.1.txt
  -> 20171103 (Dir)
        -> images (Dir)
        -> test.banana.2.txt
```

I want to change file name pattern apple to banana while making symbolic link.

In result, 
In original dir, test.apple.1.txt remains

In symbolic link, test.banana.1.txt remains

I find show pattern change shell script below:

```
for i in `find .`; do echo `echo $i | sed -e 's/apple/banana/'`; done;
```

But making symbolic link is difficult..

Is it possible?

Comment: What did you try for yourself? Update the efforts into the question

Comment: What the...?  if you link Test2 to Test, the contents under both will always be the same.  You cannot have a "real" directory with some contents under it, and the link to it display different contents.  A link is just another way to get to the same destination, you can't change the destination.  Ex. if you get to US via Canada or via Mexico, US is the US...  I guess I don't understand your question.